# Aggregate a map of objects by key

Tags: go

I am trying to create a map of objects from two maps in Go.

The first Map holds the keys. The second Map has objects with the keys as values.

Basically in this example - there are rules and detection of these rules. In the end - I want a map with the rule names as keys and a map of detections attached to them (aggregating them).

In the end: I want something like this (taken from the Typescript example below):

```
[LOG]: {
  "rule1": [
    {
      "name": "rule1",
      "message": "I found rule1"
    },
    {
      "name": "rule1",
      "message": "I found rule1 again"
    }
  ],
  "rule2": [
    {
      "name": "rule2",
      "message": "I found rule2"
    },
    {
      "name": "rule2",
      "message": "I found rule2 again"
    },
    {
      "name": "rule2",
      "message": "I found rule2 another time"
    }
  ]
}
```

In order to show this I have created this in Typescript:

[Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBASgrgG2gXigbwFBW1AdgQwFsIAuKAZ2ACcBLXAcwwF8MNRIoARCYCAY2A0A9riipMOPEVIVqdegBosOYuXL56MyrQbNW7aAEF69KhHr5eAE268Bw3OTHpl2ANpVEWuQwC6ZN1t%20QREAfl8Abig9Vj4RSihPJHIyeCQ3X2c3VxdJSQJiMgAiJIgARiKcpiVJCTzsApkSrwAmSskWSNj44CgrHmCIKzIg%20xEMrJy6%20sbi0oqa%20qhVdU1igEkoADMhOFwrRK8KqsXsabzZqGakBZzJFY0mzZ29g-moDXw6dpxqqbucJdrhA2qc8g81ldnrt9ockG0Tv8llJCldSqCAdgIU9tjC3q0PhZvojked8tI5q0imD7hA1I8NrjXnCQR9cEJgAALCBUKCCYg-bB-LqsDBIXoaUzmSxDUYhRxkYxSizWOUOJziJgRVg7XkACjijl6pSgQi2LPIAEpcjhJWYVbKBmNHB4vAA6RqZVAZbUsDC6qAGnp9J3y03m-p2azW8526Wq0PqtyR4IOD3SXxusBwcicvUp52WmKG8hCJBuhBCeh6uMOmyJ%20KWiJAA)

When I am trying to to the same in Go - I somewhat have a mental block, to do this:

[Go Playground](https://play.golang.com/p/I5KGzQjweTf)

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type Rule struct {
    Name string `json:"name"`
}

type Detection struct {
    Name    string `json:"name"`
    Message string `json:"message"`
}

func main() {

    rules := []Rule{
        {
            Name: "rule1",
        },
        {
            Name: "rule2",
        },
    }

    detected := []Detection{
        {
            Name:    "rule1",
            Message: "I found rule1",
        },
        {
            Name:    "rule1",
            Message: "I found rule1 again",
        },
        {
            Name:    "rule2",
            Message: "I found rule2",
        },
        {
            Name:    "rule2",
            Message: "I found rule2 again",
        },
        {
            Name:    "rule2",
            Message: "I found rule2 another time",
        },
    }

    fmt.Println(rules)
    fmt.Println(detected)

    aggregatedDetections := map[string][]Detection{}

    for _, r := range rules {
        fmt.Printf("Assign %s to aggregatedDetections\n", r.Name)
    }

    fmt.Println(aggregatedDetections)

}
```

I understand, that a Go veteran will need < 1 Minute for this ;) However: Even though I think I have the basic idea of maps in go - I do no know what is expected here. Especially how I can assign empty array values in the map, in order to populate them in the next step.

My question is finally: How can I get the desired output.

Comment: I've answered your question, but I think I don't really understand the final desired result. Why do you need the Rules slice, if the Detection slice's item's Name contains the rule name already?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check if a map element is exists with `if _, found := map[element]; found {}` then if not, create it with an empty slice. Then you can add the elements to the slice.

See code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type Rule struct {
    Name string `json:"name"`
}

type Detection struct {
    Name    string `json:"name"`
    Message string `json:"message"`
}

func main() {

    rules := []Rule{
        {
            Name: "rule1",
        },
        {
            Name: "rule2",
        },
    }

    detected := []Detection{
        {
            Name:    "rule1",
            Message: "I found rule1",
        },
        {
            Name:    "rule1",
            Message: "I found rule1 again",
        },
        {
            Name:    "rule2",
            Message: "I found rule2",
        },
        {
            Name:    "rule2",
            Message: "I found rule2 again",
        },
        {
            Name:    "rule2",
            Message: "I found rule2 another time",
        },
    }

    fmt.Println(rules)
    fmt.Println(detected)

    aggregatedDetections := make(map[string][]Detection)

    for _, r := range rules {
        if _, found := aggregatedDetections[r.Name]; !found {
          aggregatedDetections[r.Name] = make([]Detection, 0)
        }
        msg := ""
        switch {
          case len(aggregatedDetections[r.Name]) == 0:
             msg = "I found " + r.Name
          case len(aggregatedDetections[r.Name]) == 1:
             msg = "I found " + r.Name+" again"
        default:             
             msg = "I found " + r.Name+" another time"
        }
        aggregatedDetections[r.Name] = append(aggregatedDetections[r.Name], Detection{
          Name: r.Name,
          Message: msg,
        })
        fmt.Printf("Assign %s to aggregatedDetections\n", r.Name)
    }

    fmt.Println(aggregatedDetections)

}
```

[Playground](https://play.golang.com/p/HFnLXkUc2lx)

Comment: This does not yield the desired output. It does not take the second "detected" map into account.  The rules map defines the rule names. The detected collects the found rules. The goal is, to cluster the detected rules by rule name - in order to display them in an aggegated way.

Comment: I got it working though with part of the code above. So answer accepted. https://play.golang.com/p/XLM37e3s-5n

Comment: Yes, I asked you about it under your question. Anyway, thanks for the accept, and I'm glad I could help.